# Programmatically define openLayers 4 ol.format.filter.and

Tags: openlayers

I am currently using OpenLayers v4.6.4.

I am successfully using the ol.format.WFS to create my desired layer.

```
var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
    srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureNS: 'http://myserver',
    featurePrefix: 'locations',
    featureTypes: ['photos'],
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
    filter: ol.format.filter.and(
                ol.format.filter.during('DATE', '2015-11-27T05:00:00Z', 
                                        '2015-12-31T05:00:00Z'),
               ol.format.filter.exactTo('Category', 'Church')
           )
```

The filter is hard coded at this point.  What I need to be able to do is construct the ol.format.filter.and object using values in my dropdown boxes.  I have successfully created a function that outputs a string that exactly matches the above filter. When I physically copy the string output (filterString) from my function and paste it into the above featureRequest, I get the desired results.  If I reference filterString, I get an error when OL is trying to construct the filter.

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly related to OpenLayers, it's more about your JavaScript knowledge

You can create a function to provide an objet to `new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature(`

So your code

```
var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
    srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureNS: 'http://myserver',
    featurePrefix: 'locations',
    featureTypes: ['photos'],
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
    filter: ol.format.filter.and(
        ol.format.filter.during('DATE', '2015-11-27T05:00:00Z',
                                '2015-12-31T05:00:00Z'),
        ol.format.filter.exactTo('Category', 'Church')
    )
});
```

would turn to

```
var getFeatureParams = function(filter) {
    return {
        srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureNS: 'http://myserver',
        featurePrefix: 'locations',
        featureTypes: ['photos'],
        outputFormat: 'application/json',
        filter: filter
    }
}

var yourDynamicFilter = ol.format.filter.and(
    ol.format.filter.during('DATE', '2015-11-27T05:00:00Z',
                            '2015-12-31T05:00:00Z'),
   ol.format.filter.exactTo('Category', 'Church')
);

var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature(getFeatureParams(yourDynamicFilter));
```

PS: code written using ES5 style, you may want to upgrade to ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

That's because, `filter` requires an object not a string.You have to create a filter object, something like this:

```
var value1 = '<source of value>';
var value2 = '<source of value>';
var value3 = '<source of value>';

var f = ol.format.filter;
var filters = f.and(
  ol.format.filter.during('DATE', value1,
    value2),
  ol.format.filter.exactTo('Category', value3)
)

var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
      srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureNS: 'http://myserver',
      featurePrefix: 'locations',
      featureTypes: ['photos'],
      outputFormat: 'application/json',
      filter: filters
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to dynamically change the content of the filters (add or remove) you can define an array of filters and then pass it to the function using [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
var filterArray = [
  ol.format.filter.during('DATE', '2015-11-27T05:00:00Z', '2015-12-31T05:00:00Z'),
  ol.format.filter.exactTo('Category', 'Church')
];

var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
  srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureNS: 'http://myserver',
  featurePrefix: 'locations',
  featureTypes: ['photos'],
  outputFormat: 'application/json',
  filter: ol.format.filter.and.apply(null, filterArray)
});
```